# How to concatenate values in a column in an array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to concatenate the values in the first column in pairs.
This is better illustrated by the example

```
import numpy as np
m = np.array([[11,12,13],[21,22,23],[31,32,33],[41,42,43]])

array([[11, 12, 13],
       [21, 22, 23],
       [31, 32, 33],
       [41, 42, 43]])
```

required output

```
11 21
21 31
31 41
```

The array size is not fixed

It is possible?

Comment: I don't get the logic

Comment: OP, I think you meant for the first pair to be `11 21` otherwise it doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: Shouldn't the first row of your output example be `11 21`?

Comment: I am sorry .I fixed that mistake, Yes it's supposed to be there 11 21

Comment: @StevanNixon. You seem to have a habit of not selecting answers to your questions. Please select an answer once you get one that satisfies your needs by clicking on the check mark next to the answer you like. This will remove your question from the unanswered queue. You can do to your [user page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15099153/stevan-nixon) and select answers to your previous questions as well.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is to stack the elements you care about:

```
np.stack((m[:-1, 0], m[1:, 0]), axis=-1)
```

The more complex solution is to make a view into the data:

```
np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(m[:, 0], shape=(m.shape[0] - 1, 2), strides=(m.strides[0], m.strides[0]))
```

The first solution is straightforward and robust, but creates a copy of the data. The second solution creates a view into the original array. If you modify the view, you will see changes in the original array.

Comment: `numpy` never ceases to amaze me

Comment: @blorgon. You're referring to that second one?

Comment: Yeah, messing with strides is something I have not worked up the courage to look into yet.

Comment: @blorgon. It's how stuff like transposing works too: just swap the number of elements you need to go to get to the next element in that dimension.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you meant `11 21`, in which case here's one solution:

```py
>>> np.array([*zip(m[:,0], m[1:,0])])
array([[11, 21],
       [21, 31],
       [31, 41]])
```

To make it more general:

```py
>>> c = 0
>>> np.array([*zip(m[:, c], m[1:, c])])
array([[11, 21],
       [21, 31],
       [31, 41]])
```

To explain: `zip` exhausts with the shortest iterable given. You can create overlapping pairs of a sequence quite easily then by simply zipping the sequence with an offset slice:

```py
>>> x = [*range(10)]
>>> x
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> [*zip(x, x[1:])]
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7), (7, 8), (8, 9)]
```

Comment: I'm sure there's a way to do it using numpy, but I don't feel like reading through the docs right now :D

Comment: Call `np.stack` instead of `zip`

Comment: Nice, thanks. There's always a `numpy` solution lol.

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy indexing:

```
m[[np.arange(3),np.arange(1,4)],0].T
```

or `numpy.hstack`

```
np.hstack([m[:3,0, np.newaxis], m[1:4,0,np.newaxis]])
```

Both give:

```
array([[11, 21],
       [21, 31],
       [31, 41]])
```